# log4net reference dropped from project created with CodeDom

Tags: c#, log4net

We have code that gets compiled into a library using CodeDom. In some of these classes I would like to add log4net statements.

When adding the references to the project that will be created using CodeDom we have this:

```
            references.Add("mscorlib.dll");
            references.Add("System.dll");
            references.Add("System.Data.dll");
            references.Add("System.Xml.dll");
            references.Add("System.Core.dll");
            references.Add("System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll");
            references.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
            references.Add(Path.Combine(m_Settings.BinPath, "log4net.dll"));
            references.Add(Path.Combine(m_Settings.Engine.EngineBinPath, "Engines.Calculation.dll"));
```

When I debug, the `references` contain an entry for log4net, but in the resulting project, it is missing. The log4net.dll is in the m_Settings.BinPath, and no exception is thrown when added to `references`.

When the project is finished being created I get the usual error message:

> The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I add it manually all is well, but it needs to be generated.

The .Net framework being targeted is 4.6, but the log4net version is 1.2.13.0. However, this does not seem to be a problem in the rest of the solution.

Why does it drop the log4net reference from the `references` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two places in the code that the references are created. The case above was the first scenario (and with some execution paths the only scenario), but another place also exists which didn't have the log4net reference added and that is how it seemed to be dropped in the final scheme.
So I've added the log4net reference at both places and it works fine now.